# I think this old, upvoted answer is wrong

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

The Answer I'm referring to:
https://security.stackexchange.com/a/5357/61443

My objections to it are:

1. While the OP is asking about recovering the AES keys, his setup is also vulnerable to a Ciphertext Indistinguishably attack.
2. **Dangerously** for other users / DB admins who find this question is that the answer of "Nah, everything's fine" is dangerously misleading without also mentioning IVs, and making sure your PRNG has a good entropy source somewhere in the body of the question.

So, do others agree with my assessment, and if so, can we change it?

Comment: Why not make a reply calling him out? And reply as a comment as well, stating that he's wrong, etc.

Comment: I did, but since the post is 5 years old, I have low hopes that he'll log in to see it. -- actually, he logged in January 2016, so maybe there's some hope.

Comment: Make an answer calling him out as well.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that shortly.

Comment: If his concern is security of the key, as the questioner explicitly states, then the accepted answer is technically correct.  It ignores the Indistinguishability attack, but that may not be a threat that concerns him.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, on Mark Buffalo's suggestion, I posted a [Community Wiki Answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/117509/61443).

I do not feel that I am enough of an expert here, so I ask that other people look over it and fix any errors or inaccuracies.

Answer (score 3):

That answer is not incorrect, but it is incomplete. As you noticed there is a serious design flaw in the implementation described in the question. The question does not explicitly ask about this weakness, and the answer does not mention it.

Though technically a correct answer to the question as it was asked, it is indeed a disservice to provide the answer as such without pointing out the quite severe weakness.

I edited your [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/117509/47143) to address one minor issue. But even before my edit it was a better answer than the accepted one.